# Explanation requested for deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answer

Just curious why my answer on [**this question**](https://superuser.com/questions/264547/weird-boxes-with-symbols-on-toolbar) (10K / mod obviously required to view my answer) was deleted by a mod.  If the reason is that it sounds like a comment, then I take exception to that because I give a perfectly viable possibility in my answer.  If the SU community is that different to SO or SF and doesn't welcome that kind of an answer then just let me know and I'll happily move along to other questions.

Comment: SU does like a vigorous scrubbing

Comment: @random Well put, I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer was flagged as "not an answer"...It belongs as a comment to the question, as you are suggesting that the asker post a screenshot to help troubleshoot his problem...converted to comment, but someone else has already suggested the same thing...

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've certainly seen worse, but I can roll with that.

Comment: thanks for your understanding @squillman...see my updated answer...

Comment: Oh, certainly.  I figured it was something along those lines.  I admittedly don't live in SU as much as the others.

Comment: its no problem @squillman, we're happy to help...